# Breadcrumbs: Search result not displayed when static page is on top

Tags: search, breadcrumb

Uhm, this is quite a weird problem and I'm trying to make sure that I explain it well enough so that you understand what I'm talking about.

So, I'm using breadcrumbs in my header area. 
It all works fine. However, when you type in a search, it only SOMETIMES displays the actual search result in the breadcrumbs. It's supposed to look like that:
Home » Blog » Search results for "lorem"
[View it live](http://www.zoomingjapan.com/?s=lorem).

However, if the first search result (the one that is being displayed on top of all others) is a static page instead of a blog post, the breadcrumbs display it this way:
Home » Blog » Page
[View it live](http://www.zoomingjapan.com/?s=japan).
It's still shown correctly in the tab of my browser. Only the breadcrumbs seem to get confused.

This is the code snippet I use for the breadcrumbs:

```
function dimox_breadcrumbs() {

  $delimiter = '<span class="delimiter">&raquo;</span>';
  $home = 'Home'; // text for the 'Home' link
  $before = '<span class="current">'; // tag before the current crumb
  $after = '</span>'; // tag after the current crumb

  if ( !is_front_page() || is_paged() ) {

    echo '<div id="crumbs">';

global $post;
$divider = $delimiter;
if (is_home()) $divider = '';
$homeLink = get_bloginfo('url');
echo '<a href="' . $homeLink . '" rel="nofollow">' . $home . '</a> ' . $delimiter . ' <a href="http://www.zoomingjapan.com/blog/" rel="nofollow">Blog</a> ' . $divider . ' ';

    if ( is_category() ) {
      global $wp_query;
      $cat_obj = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
      $thisCat = $cat_obj->term_id;
      $thisCat = get_category($thisCat);
      $parentCat = get_category($thisCat->parent);
      if ($thisCat->parent != 0) echo(get_category_parents($parentCat, TRUE, ' ' . $delimiter . ' '));
      echo $before . 'Archive by category "' . single_cat_title('', false) . '"' . $after;

    } elseif ( is_day() ) {
      echo '<a href="' . get_year_link(get_the_time('Y')) . '">' . get_the_time('Y') . '</a> ' . $delimiter . ' ';
      echo '<a href="' . get_month_link(get_the_time('Y'),get_the_time('m')) . '">' . get_the_time('F') . '</a> ' . $delimiter . ' ';
      echo $before . get_the_time('d') . $after;

    } elseif ( is_month() ) {
      echo '<a href="' . get_year_link(get_the_time('Y')) . '">' . get_the_time('Y') . '</a> ' . $delimiter . ' ';
      echo $before . get_the_time('F') . $after;

    } elseif ( is_year() ) {
      echo $before . get_the_time('Y') . $after;

    } elseif ( is_single() && !is_attachment() ) {
      if ( get_post_type() != 'post' ) {
        $post_type = get_post_type_object(get_post_type());
        $slug = $post_type->rewrite;
        echo '<a href="' . $homeLink . '/' . $slug['slug'] . '/">' . $post_type->labels->singular_name . '</a> ' . $delimiter . ' ';
        echo $before . get_the_title() . $after;
      } else {
        $cat = get_the_category(); $cat = $cat[0];
        echo get_category_parents($cat, TRUE, ' ' . $delimiter . ' ');
        echo $before . get_the_title() . $after;
      }

    } elseif ( !is_single() && !is_page() && get_post_type() != 'post' && !is_404() ) {
      $post_type = get_post_type_object(get_post_type());
      echo $before . $post_type->labels->singular_name . $after;

    } elseif ( is_attachment() ) {
      $parent = get_post($post->post_parent);
      $cat = get_the_category($parent->ID); $cat = $cat[0];
      echo get_category_parents($cat, TRUE, ' ' . $delimiter . ' ');
      echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($parent) . '">' . $parent->post_title . '</a> ' . $delimiter . ' ';
      echo $before . get_the_title() . $after;

    } elseif ( is_page() && !$post->post_parent ) {
      echo $before . get_the_title() . $after;

    } elseif ( is_page() && $post->post_parent ) {
      $parent_id  = $post->post_parent;
      $breadcrumbs = array();
      while ($parent_id) {
        $page = get_page($parent_id);
        $breadcrumbs[] = '<a href="' . get_permalink($page->ID) . '">' . get_the_title($page->ID) . '</a>';
        $parent_id  = $page->post_parent;
      }
      $breadcrumbs = array_reverse($breadcrumbs);
      foreach ($breadcrumbs as $crumb) echo $crumb . ' ' . $delimiter . ' ';
      echo $before . get_the_title() . $after;

    } elseif ( is_search() ) {
      echo $before . 'Search results for "' . get_search_query() . '"' . $after;

    } elseif ( is_tag() ) {
      echo $before . 'Posts tagged "' . single_tag_title('', false) . '"' . $after;

    } elseif ( is_author() ) {
       global $author;
      $userdata = get_userdata($author);
      echo $before . 'Articles posted by ' . $userdata->display_name . $after;

    } elseif ( is_404() ) {
      echo $before . 'Error 404' . $after;
    }

    if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
if (is_home()) echo ' ' . $delimiter . ' ';
      if ( is_category() || is_day() || is_month() || is_year() || is_search() || is_tag() || is_author() ) echo ' (';
      echo __('Page') . ' ' . get_query_var('paged');
      if ( is_category() || is_day() || is_month() || is_year() || is_search() || is_tag() || is_author() ) echo ')';
    }

    echo '</div>';

  }
} // end dimox_breadcrumbs()
```

I already talked to the creator of the code, but he also has no clue why this is ocurring.
I hope somebody has at least a clue so that I can work on it?

Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to change this part:

```
echo $before . 'Search results for "' . get_search_query() . '"' . $after;
```

To this:

```
$searchTerm = get_search_query()
echo $before . 'Search results for "' . $searchTerm . '"' . $after;
```

Comment: So, i understand that fixed that? gr8 man - good luck :)

Comment: Sorry, your code is producing the following syntax error: unexpected T_ECHO

Comment: If I add a ";" after the get_search_query, then the syntax error disappears, but the code doesn't do anything, the problem is not solved.